# How can I use bash function for date values

Tags: bash, function

I have log file(xferlog) like this:

```
Mon Jan  5 09:52:58 2015 1 10.0.0.1 0 /home/DATA1/123.sqlLdr b _ i r DATA1 ftp 0 * c
```

I need ftp transfer date for all patterns(last transfer) like this:

```
201501050952 ( yearmonthdayhourminute )
```

I can do like this:

```
xfer1=$(tac "/var/log/xferlog" | awk -v pattern="DATA1" '$9 ~ pattern {print; exit}')

day1=${xfer1:8:2}
month1=${xfer1:4:3}
year1=${xfer1:20:4}
hour1=${xfer1:11:2}
minute1=${xfer1:14:2}

# For converting Jan, Feb... --> 01, 02

if [ "$month1" == "Jan" ];then
month1=01
fi
if [ "$month1" == "Feb" ];then
month1=02
...

# For converting month - 1,2,3 --> 01, 02, 03

day1s=$day1
if [ "$day1" == " 1" ];then
day1s=01
fi
if [ "$day1" == " 2" ];then
day1s=02
fi
...

echo "DATA1: $year1$month1$day1s$hour1$minute1"
...
```

It's work but I need to do same process for other patterns. Like this:

```
xfer1=$(tac "/var/log/xferlog" | awk -v pattern="DATA1" '$9 ~ pattern {print; exit}')
xfer2=$(tac "/var/log/xferlog" | awk -v pattern="LIN5" '$9 ~ pattern {print; exit}')
...
```

How can I use function for converting date format and use all patterns? And how can I use variables in function? I can do different variable name and converting(day1 day2 day3...), but it's so long and not usual.

Comment: you might take a look at the "date" command... (look in the man pages: `man date`)

Comment: I know a little bit. Can you show me some example please? I need to see some example about function and date function for easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python, I hope it's fairly self-explanatory.  I've edited it to actually make it a "Bash" snippet which embeds a Python script.

```
tac "/var/log/xferlog" | python -c "
import datetime
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    path = line.split()[8]
    user = path.split('/')[2]
    if user in ('DATA1', 'LIN5'):
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[:24], '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
        print dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
"
```

Comment: @iyonizer: I have to admit, I'm curious why not.  Do you have an operating system more than ten years old?

Comment: No, but it is part of my bash script. So that's why maybe I can do easy way for bash. We can do with C too, maybe easy way. But if I found easy solution with bash, I use. If I can't find, my bash script already working (maybe not usual, but work).

Comment: I'm confused: you're using `awk` which is not part of Bash, already, right?  Is awk preferable to python for some reason?

Comment: Can I use Python codes in my bash script? If yes, sorry, I didn't know  that :). Because I can use awk in script.

Comment: @iyonizer: I have updated my answer to show how you can put it directly in your Bash script.

Comment: Thanks, it's work for me. I didn't know that I can use python like this.

Comment: This doesn't quit when it finds and prints the first match.  If there are multiple matches, it will print them all.

Comment: @tripleee: right, well, you can just add a line saying `break` after the one that does `print`.

Comment: But that will cause it to only print the first pattern.  You should somehow avoid printing a pattern more than once, and exit only when you have seen them all.

Answer (score 1):

Looping over the patterns you already have is a no-brainer.

```
for pat in DATA1 LIN5; do
    xfer=$(tac /var/log/xferlog |
        awk -v pattern="$pat" '$9 ~ pattern { print; exit }')
    : massive ugly date processing here
    echo "$PAT: $year1$month1$day1s$hour1$minute1"
done
```

You can easily factor the date processing into the Awk script, too.

```
for pat in DATA1 LIN5; do
    tac /var/log/xferlog |
    awk -v pattern="$pat" 'BEGIN {
        m="Jan:Feb:Mar:Apr:May:Jun:Sep:Oct:Nov:Dec";
        n=split(m, mm, /:/); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) month[mm[i]]=i; }
        $9 ~ pattern { printf("%s: %04i%02i%02i%02i%02i\n", pattern,
            substr($0, 21, 4), month[substr($0, 5, 3)], 0+substr($0, 9, 2),
            substr($0, 12,2), substr($0, 15, 2)); exit }'
done
```

To make processing more efficient, you could factor the patterns into the Awk script as well.  Keeping track of the list of patterns and quitting when you have found them all is a minor complication, though.

```
tac /var/log/xferlog |
awk 'BEGIN { pat["DATA"]=1; pat["LIN5"]=1; 
    m="Jan:Feb:Mar:Apr:May:Jun:Sep:Oct:Nov:Dec";
    n=split(m, mm, /:/); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) month[mm[i]]=i; }
    { for (k in pat) if ($9 ~ pat[k]) { printf("%s: %04i%02i%02i%02i%02i\n", pattern,
        substr($0, 21, 4), month[substr($0, 5, 3)], 0+substr($0, 9, 2),
        substr($0, 12,2), substr($0, 15, 2)); delete pat[k]; break }
    length(pat) == 0 { exit }'
```